# how to concat to an 'indexed' objects in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

[image]I have reducer which changes structure [{}] or [{},{}] on 
[0:{}] or [0:{},1:{}]

after this change I cant concat to this original array. Is there any solution for this case?
I must add that its really hard to change reducer that it is not genereting changed structure of array(it`is my opinion)

I add the reducer code:

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions';
import {schema, normalize, arrayOf} from 'normalizr';
import _ from 'lodash';


const iniState = {
  recipes : []
}

function createRecipe(state = iniState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.ADD_RECIPE:
      let newRecipe = {
        id: Math.floor(Math.random()*10000),
        re: action.payload.recipeInReducer,
        c: action.payload.compsInReducer
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        recipes: state.recipes.concat(newRecipe)
      }
      case actionTypes.EDIT_BOOLEAN:
      return {...state,
        recipes: {..._.map(state.recipes, recipe=>{
          if(recipe.id === action.payload.idFromRecipe){
            return Object.assign({}, recipe, {
              c: {..._.map(recipe.c, comp=>{
                if(comp.id === action.payload.idFromComp){
                  return {...comp,
                  toRecipe: !comp.toRecipe};
                }else{return comp}
              })
            }
            })
          } else{
            return Object.assign({}, recipe, {
              c: {..._.map(recipe.c, comp=>comp)}})
          }
        })
      }
}

 }
  return state;
}
export default createRecipe;
```

Comment: `[0:{}]` is not a valid structure in javascript.

Comment: I added a picture, so it is invalid but it was made by javascripts function, how??

Comment: Post your reducer code

Comment: seems like you misspelled `{ 0: {}, 1: {} }` as `[0: {}, 1: {}]`, otherwise it's not clear, or not OK at all

Comment: I have wrote well: array of objects: [0: {}, 2:{}]

Comment: btw, `{ ...something }` returns an object, even if the content of `something` is an array.

Comment: Your btw was the clue for me! :) It is logic. I was learning about creating proper structure, {} was this what was remained from last update. Now everything for me is Clear :) thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the object by using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), which take the keys as indices for an array.

```js
var object = { 0: { foo: 0 }, 1: { bar: 42 } },
    array = Object.assign([], object);
    
console.log(array);
```